# I want to know currently opened all urls in any browser

Tags: curl, browser

I want to know currently opened all urls in any browser. Is this information is present somewhere in system in log files? How can i see currently opened urls programatically? or If any where in any system files this list is made by browsers?

Kindly give the logical solution so can be implemented in any programming language.

Comment: Where on a system this data is based is only known through several variables: 1) the user details (ie login name), 2) the system type (windows, Mac, Linux), 3) the browser (chrome, Safari,etc). I think as it stands this question is too broad and too vague. Clarify your situation and for my own interest, why, why would you need to know activity in other browser windows? This would also very probably be remote-access-isolated data.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have a .html file and i want to give a prompt to user from deleting that file, if that file is opened in any browser. I think i have made my question clear

Comment: browsers store cached copies of files, so the html that is on the browser will not be the exact same file as the one on the server, transportation servers also store cached copies of some files, particularly html, so it would be better to assume that whatever they try to delete will be open somewhere, but the deleting of it itself doesn't effect that [locally opened] instance.

Comment: I have a .html file in my system and i want to know if it is currently accessible by any browser? Is it possible to write a piece of code which will return 0 or 1 for this?